# Como funcionan las propiedades de navegación en CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net, base-de-datos, mvc, entity-framework, model

¿Cómo funcionan las propiedades de navegación en CodeFirst?

```
public class Estudiante{

    public int EstudianteID { get; set; }
    public Estudiante _Estudiante { get; set; }
    public InformacionBasica info { get; set; }
    public virtual List<InformacionBasica> InfoBasic { get; set; }
}

public class InformacionBasica{
    public int InfoEstudianteID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public List<string> Pais { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No te faltó la etiqueta de Entity Framework? Aparte, no estaría de mas que publicaras la otra clase, InformacionBasica.

Comment: Listo gracias por responder :)

Comment: Contestando a tu pregunta, las propiedades de navegación en EF permiten definir las relaciones entre tablas (uno a uno/uno a muchos/muchos a muchos) y poder cargar los datos de una entidad junto con los datos relacionados. Por ejemplo, si configuras tus entidades bien, puedes cargar los datos de un estudiante y cargar de la base de datos no solo los datos de la tabla de estudiantes sino también los datos de la tabla de información básica que están relavionados con ese estudiante. Necesitas configurar tus clases indicando la relación entre cada clase, ya sea mediante atributos o por fluent api.

Comment: Yo creo que debes modificar esas dos clases. En tu clase estudiante mete todo la información que está directamente relacionada con un estudiante y no se repite en otro estudiante, por ejemplo nombre y apellido yo las movería a la clase estudiante. Quitaría la propiedad "_Estudiante", ya que con eso le estás diciendo al EF que un estudiante está relacionado con otro estudiante, y no creo que quieras eso. Luego lo que sea relacionado con un estudiante, pero se pueda repetir en otros estudiantes, por ejemplo pais, lo metería en otra clase y en la clase estudiante metería una propiedad país.